# Unable to post data from child to parent in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jqwidget

I'm working in single page web application. In page i have a dropdown so based on dropdown value i will load the data in grid. The grid data is come from jqgrid component so sometime grid data is still loading and user change the dropdown so previous server request is not complete and user hit a new request to server so i want a solution for this problem. so i have decided to disable the dropdown until the data is not fully loaded so i make a variable in state with value false (first time dropdown is disabled) and when the data is loaded make it true. but problem is that i'm unable to update the state of parent from child.

i have create a function called

```
handleChange(e)
{
this.setState({ isDisabled: false });
}
```

and in my state i have set isDisabled value true. i.e means by default it is disable. In child component jqwidget data adapter in callback i'm calling the parent function.

```
let dataAdapter = new jqx.dataAdapter(currentComponent.state.source,{ formatData: function (data) { },
loadComplete: function (data) 
 {
            this.props.handler(false)
            //console.log(data);

 }.bind(this)
```

i'm not putting my complete code you can check the snippets [here](https://gist.github.com/imsonujangra/cf8d6767a4f28b3931e3b1d7a5ab3649).so how to update the parent state from child.

Comment: Can you show as the Complete Components code so that we can help you. This is not going to help in solving your problem.

Comment: have u checked the code snippets.https://gist.github.com/imsonujangra/cf8d6767a4f28b3931e3b1d7a5ab3649

Comment: you shouldn't call your adapter in the render function, because everytime your state or props change it will be called (and you don't want that).

Comment: ok so where should i call the adapter function.

Comment: what about using redux? have the child component triggering an action, and then update the parent's state according to your store.

Comment: @truesource, Did you try `currentComponent.props.handler(false)` instead of `this.props.handler(false)`?

Comment: @mihai1990 it's not working currentComponent.props.handler(false)

Comment: @Barazu i don't have a idea about redux. but i want to update the parent state when the child component have loads the data.

Comment: one more thing my child component api call twice for the first time. why ?

Comment: @truesource can you try logging `this.props` in the load callback function and comment the result? And as mentioned, it shouldn't be inside `render` (or it will be called any time the component is rendered (which is probably why it's called twice). Put it inside `componentDidMount` (ideally inside a separate component that handles the business logic - I recommend you to do some reading on presentational components and containers).

Comment: @Barazu i'm using jqwidget grid and for refreshing the data based on dropdown change ex. https://www.jqwidgets.com/react/react-grid/react-grid-refreshdata.htm